# How do I change the order of the Gradient in Format Column with AG Grid and AdapTable

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am using the Gradient Column style in our AG Grid which we use with AdapTable.

My column has both positive and negative numbers. So I have created one Range - which colours red - for the negative numbers and another, which colours green, for the positive numbers.

The positive range works fine and the larger the number the darker the Green.
But in the negative range the cell is darker the nearer it is to 0, which is the wrong way round for me.  I want it to be darker the **lower** the (negative) number.  Is this possible?

My Format Column definition is as follows:

```
FormatColumn: {
  FormatColumns: [
      {
        Scope: { ColumnIds: ['current_value']},
        ColumnStyle: {
          GradientStyle: {
            CellRanges: [
              {Min: -100, Max: 0, Color: 'Red'},
              {Min: 0, Max: 100, Color: 'Green'}
            ],
          },
        },
        DisplayFormat: { Formatter: 'NumberFormatter', Options: { Parentheses: true}},
        CellAlignment: 'Center',
      },
    ],
  },
```

Comment: Can someone help me to do the same in angular? I have calculated the weight for the rgb channel values. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73653458/how-to-apply-linear-gradient-scheme-on-ag-grid-cells-angular

Answer (score 2):

The Range has an optional `ReverseGradient` boolean property with a default value of false.

You need to provide this in your negative range and set it to true

```
CellRanges: [
  {Min: -100, Max: 0, Color: 'Red', ReverseGradient: true },
  {Min: 0, Max: 100, Color: 'Green'}
],
```